# Is it efficient to run AsyncTask<> in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I want to implement such a task: in  the background (when app is in the background) look for new data for the user and give notifications about it. I have to do this periodically (every 2-3 seconds).There is different data so I use different methods for this (FetchImages ,FetchMessages, FetchNewConversations , etc.)As far as I know in Android 4 all network operations must be implemented in the backgroun thread, so I implement all this operations as classes inherited from AsyncTask and then to call them I just write `FetchImages.execute ()` But activities execute only once so I decided to call them via  `ScheduledExecutorService` like this:

```
.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() 
   {
  FetchImages.execute(); //...
    }
```

So the question is it a good idea or there exeist better and more efficient solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ScheduledExecutorService` already uses a background thread, you do not need to add *another* background thread via `AsyncTask`. In fact, your code should crash, as you can only create an `AsyncTask` on the main application thread.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me some snippet how to use it correctly in my case?
Should I create different ScheduledExecutorServices for each of my task FetchImages ,FetchMessages or I must implement some generic thread manager?

Comment: @HarryCater: "Can you give me some snippet how to use it correctly in my case?" -- no, but `ScheduledExecutorService` has been around for years, and so a search engine should turn up examples. "Should I create different ScheduledExecutorServices for each of my task FetchImages ,FetchMessages or I must implement some generic thread manager?" -- probably neither. Call `scheduleAtFixedRate()` multiple times.

Comment: Along with CommonsWare's helpful advice, may I plead that you _not_ create a background task that checks something "every 2-3 seconds"? There can be nothing so important that you need that frequency.